# Sunsopt Solr Not Searching Zips That Start With 0

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, full-text-search, sunspot-rails

I am Using [SunSpot Solr](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) for Searching text and zip codes through my application.
I am searching through the model like below,

```
  searchable do
    text :city
    integer :zip
  end

  def self.search_with_solr(search_word)
    search = Hometown.solr_search do
      fulltext(search_word)
    end
    search.results
  end
```

Whenever I search through for zip codes and city (eg. 123 and blah) it returns me result,
But if I search for zips that start with 0 (eg. 001243) it doesnt return me the result.

I guess configuration needs to be changed in schema.xml. I tried Every combination but in vein.
Would be obliged if I get a quick response.

Comment: You might want to include your schema.xml next time. But having to guess I think using N-Grams will fix your problem.

Comment: Okke: Thanks a lot buddy. I have used N-Grams Filter Factory. Just got a solution! I was using a integer field for storing zip codes. I used string with character limit of 6 and I got the results in searches! Will post as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be a small change!

I was using INTEGER as data type for storing zips. Converted it into STRING with character limit of 6 and got results!